# Multi Label Classification for a large number of labels

Tags: deep-learning, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

I am working on a problem where my input feature vector is of dimension 2 and I have to predict labels corresponding to each input. The set of labels is quite huge, I have about potential 1500 labels for each input.

The way I approach it now is that I make vector representation for labels as 1's and 0's, with 1 corresponding if that label is present in the input example. However, the size of the vector would be about 1500.

I tried using Logistic Regression on this and it gave very bad results, with precision being 0.0006 and recall being 0.0011.

I also used a deep learning approach, where I passed the input feature of dimension 2 through some embedding layers and then predict/classify labels with these complex features. Loss function I used for deep learning model is binary_crossentropy. But still, it does not perform better.

Please direct me to some resources that discuss the problem of multi-label classification with a very large number of labels.

Comment: You are talking about embedding layers for your input, what form is the input in? Floats? Indices for categorical values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but your description is lacking, you might want to follow this procedure when classifying a multi-label classifier.

### Step 1: Make assumptions

Let's try and simplify the problem with the most basic multi-label classifier assumption: the labels are independent.

The way to tackle this problem is to classify $\{l_1,\dots,l_k\}$ labels by training $k$ classifiers independently, where classifier $C_i(x)=1$ iff $l_i\in Labels(x)$.

### Step 2: Feature engineering

We have no idea from your question what features are reasonable for your problem.
But applying logistic regression on $x_1$ and $x_2$ would not yield good results if their relation to the label is not linear.

You could add any number of "engineered feature" such as $x_1*x_2,\frac{x_1}{x_y},\sqrt{(x_1-c_1)^2+(x_2-c_2)^2},\dots$.

And bring prior knowledge to the model, for example, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are longitude and latitude, What country / region do they represent ? climate ? earth-quake rate, etc....

### Step 3: Removing outliers and dont-cares

The best way is to plot your model or apply clustering algorithms, and see what data points pull the model to undesired places/

### Step 4: decide on an objective function

This is a multi-label classification problem, so your input of "0.0006" accuracy doesn't tell me much.

One way to measure multi-label performance, is the Jaccaard index
$$J(y_{true}, y_{pred})=\frac{|y_{pred}\cap y_{true}|}{|y_{pred}\cup y_{true}|}$$

There are plenty of other ways, and you may want to weigh the labels differently.

### Step 5: Train the classifier

Now you can train your logistic regression / NN model.

There are several packages (e.g. [MEKA](http://meka.sourceforge.net)) that specialize on multi-label models.

Answer (score 0):

In this abstract version of your problem, you could as well be solving the following problem:

You have two parameters, e.g. longitude, latitude on Earth, and want a single model to be able to tell what model car is closest to that location. I wouldn't expect good results.

I think you have to give us more detail to help you solve the problem.

Probably you have to go back to the drawing board and partition your problem.

E.g. how are the results on 1-2 labels, or about 10?

Comment: I don't see why this would be an issue, you basically have 1500 seperate tasks and if all of them individually could work, a combined model could also work (and maybe even better)